# Too many rows when Joining to same table twice

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have two tables, Product and Benchmark
A benchmark is linked to only one product. There can only be one benchmark per year per product.

I would like to retrieve every products' name for a set of years, and count how many benchmark there are for each product.

```
SELECT p.name,
       p.id,
       COUNT(p.id) AS nb_benchmark
FROM product p
INNER JOIN benchmark b0 ON b0.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN benchmark b1 ON b1.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.owner = "MyCompany"
  AND b0.year = 2011
  AND b1.year = 2012
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY nb_trials DESC
```

But the count is wrong, it's way to high, it even gives me more results than there actually are in the database. I guess it's because of the JOINs, but I don't know how to build the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to achieve what I wanted

```
      SELECT p.name, p.id,  COUNT(DISTINCT(b0.id)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(b1.id))  as     nb_benchmark
      FROM product p
      INNER JOIN benchamrk b0 ON b0.product_id = p.id AND b0.year = 2011 
      INNER JOIN benchamrk b1 ON b1.product_id = p.id AND b1.year = 2012 
      WHERE
      p.owner = "myCompany" 
      GROUP BY p.id
      ORDER BY nb_benchmark DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

Remember that the basis of SQL joining is the cartesian product of rows in the referenced tables, which are then eliminated by filters and join conditions. Because you are joining TWICE to table `benchmark`, which from the nature of your query, we can assume has many `benchmark` rows per `product` per benchmark year.

e.g. 1 Product with 3 Benchmark rows each for 2011 and 2012

```
FROM product p -- 1 Product Row
INNER JOIN benchmark b0 ON b0.product_id = p.id -- 1 x 3 = 3
INNER JOIN benchmark b1 ON b1.product_id = p.id -- 1 x 3 x 3 = 9
```

So the multiple joins to `benchmark` introduces duplicate rows for `product`, which are then counted.

You can use [`COUNT(DISTINCT xx)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) to count distinct values, so your query should be of the form:

```
SELECT p.name, 
       p.id, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS distinct_products,
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.name) AS distinct_benchmark_names
       -- etc
FROM ...
```

*Other Notes*

- for correctness sake you should  `GROUP BY` both `p.id` and `p.name`. Although MySql allows this, other RDBMS are more strict.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.name,
       p.id,
       COUNT(b0.id) AS nb_benchmark
FROM product p
INNER JOIN benchmark b0 ON b0.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.owner = "MyCompany"
  AND b0.year IN (2011, 2012)
GROUP BY p.name, p.id
ORDER BY nb_trials DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, b.nb_benchmark
FROM product p
JOIN (
    /* number of benchpark per product for years 2011 and 2012 */
    SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS nb_benchmark
    FROM benchmark
    WHERE year = 2011 OR year = 2012
    GROUP BY product_id
) b ON p.id = b.product_id
WHERE p.owner = "MyCompany"
ORDER BY nb_benchmark DESC
```

Comment: I had made a mistake in my first query, I needed an "AND" for the years condition